# Python float represented as dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, flask, caffe, gunicorn

I have some application developed in python2 using caffe as a framework to classify some types of images. The output from such system should be a numpy array, its values is the probability from softmax layer where I should take the largest value and its index as the prediction.

However, sometimes (like 3 times out of 200) the probability value is not printed in decimal representation. Instead it is in the form of a dictionary.

For example, instead of `0.02345`, I got
`{s: 1, e: -3, c: [2, 3, 4, 5]}`

Anybody have experience the same things? For additional information, the server is implemented using flask with gunicorn as web server.

Thanks!

==========================================================================

Edit: this is snippet of the code that responsible for the value

```
   for i, _ in enumerate(images):
        output_prob = self.net.blobs['prob'].data[i]
        top_indexes = output_prob.argsort()[::-1][:num_of_predictions]
        predictions = [(self.labels[j], float(output_prob[j]))
                       for j in top_indexes]
        results.append(predictions)
```

and this in different files

```
results = {}
    for i, pred in enumerate(predictions_all):
        predictions = [{'class': x[0], 'confidence': x[1]} for x in pred]
        results[image_urls[i]] = dict(predictions=predictions)
    return jsonify(results), 200
```

The full version of related libraries is numpy==1.11.1 flask==0.11.1 gunicorn==19.6.0

Comment: What is the type of the value in those cases?

Comment: Looks like some sort of arbitrary-precision decimal object; the question is, what are you doing that you're looking at the guts of such an object, instead of letting it behave as a number for math, or a string for printing?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question to include the code snippets. As can be seen, there is no funny operation here. Just take the last layer value and pick the largest value and index and then send it as json.

Another thing is, the error only occur in small number of times in production, and when we tried to reproduce it by sending the query manually, it always returns correct answer.